# Using JavaScript to obtain the body height of an HTML page even when the browser's window has been minimized in size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to print out in Google's Chrome Console the height of the body of an HTML page. And to do this I am using the below code:

```
console.log(document.body.offsetHeight)
```

The above line of code reports back the correct value when the browser's window is maximized up to a degree where the vertical scrolling bar is no longer needed.

I would like to get the same value no matter what the Browser's window size is. Is there some kind of a property that reports back the full body height of an HTML page including the height that can be scrolled through?

Comment: [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: You can use scrollHeight - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollheight2